# Handling ReadTimeoutHandler time out

Tags: java, nio, netty

I just can't realize why my read time out is not working. All I want to do is just to wait
for 10 seconds for some thread to put message to `BlockedQueue<String>` and on timeout return some kind of response on client.

```
public class NioAsynChatPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {

     private static Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
     private final ChannelHandler timeoutHandler = new ReadTimeoutHandler(timer, 10);

    @Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
         pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
         pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
         pipeline.addLast("handler", new NioAsynChatHandler());
         pipeline.addLast("timeout", this.timeoutHandler);
        return pipeline;
    }

}
```

Now my handler looks like this.

```
public class NioAsynChatHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler{

     @Override
     public void handleUpstream(
        ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelEvent e) throws Exception {
               super.handleUpstream(ctx, e);
     }

 @Override
     public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e)
        throws Exception {
         System.out.println("Exception");
        \\writing some kind of response and closing channel.
    }

    @Override
        public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new ConsmerTask(e.getChannel()));
                thread.start();

}
```

and inside ConsumerTask I'm just waiting for BlockingQueue to get response

```
public class ConsumerTask implements Runnable{

    private Channel channel;


public ConsumerTask(Channel channel){
        this.channel = channel;
}

    @Override
    public void run() {
         try{
            while(true){
              String message = queue.take();
            }
         } catch(InterruptedException ex){
           Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
         } finally{
         //write something to channel and close it   
        }
}
```

My problem is that I don't see that any excpetion occurs on time out. 
What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

```
 public static final BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
```

Actually my question is more generic, How to close channel on timeout while it is waiting for something in external thread?

**Update 2:**
Another question: due to the fact that I'm running external thread in Cha  would it be better to use `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` in pipeline? Will it increase performance.

Comment: shouldn't you use poll() instead of take? What implementation did you choose for the BlockingQueue?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter, whether I'm using poll() or take(). In poll I can specify time out and no while(true) loop required, while take() gets items immediately. Regarding blocking queue see my update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's basically because you put the `ReadTimeoutHandler` in the wrong position.  Please put it in the first position of the pipeline (i.e. before all handlers).

Comment: could you explain why?

Comment: Please take a look at the Javadoc of `ChannelPipeline` to learn about even evaluation order.